# custom effect with cakephp js helper

Tags: cakephp

I am using Js helper class and i have successfully implement this.I am using following code for using ajax.

```
$this->Js->link('test','action',array(
                'before'=>$this->Js->get('#loader')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'success'=>$this->Js->get('#front_album')->effect('fadeIn'),
                'update'=>'#front_album'));
```

Now in this when i try to add animate effect instead of fade In,nothing is happen.I try this in following manner.

```
$this->Js->get('#loader')->effect('animate','opacity: 1.0');
```

Please tell me where i am wrong and how can i add the animate effect in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [pre-specified effect names](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::effect) available in JsHelper. Instead of if you want to make `animate` effect while clicking on JsHelper link, then you'll have to make your own helper extend by JsHelper and provide the definition for that effect.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305567/triggering-event-manually-in-js-helper-cakephp) will help you to create your own helper that will support the feature you want.

This is the only way that you can use to obtain the required effect.